# Swift - Firestore create Subcollection for Array Elements

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to create a Subcollection for an array-element with Swift? I could not find anything on that topic in the documentation.

In my case I have users that have lists. In these lists the user can add/delete elements and these elements should have several attributes.

At the moment my Database looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you storing the users in an Array?

Comment: No I have a Collection and if a user signs up a new Documents gets created Along with some attributes

Comment: I believe the answer is no. But. You could keep a reference to a collection with your array element. Generally though, while Firestore has better support for Arrays than the RTDB, they are not well suited for NoSQL applications - there are usually better ways to organize your data. Perhaps you could expand your question with your use case.

Comment: @Jay I updated my question, not quite sure if that helps.

Comment: you said there are better ways to organize my data? Could you give me an example? :)

Comment: Can you provide some information (in the question) as what elements will have several attributes and what those attributes are? For example, in your question it says *In my case I have users that have lists* but nothing there is a user with a list. I don't know if we can help but providing a bit more info about what you're doing may lead to a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204005/discussion-between-chris-and-jay).